# os.environ does not return new and exported environment variables

Tags: python, macos, environment-variables

I've set a new environment variable using `export new_v = "mynewvar"`
in my `.bash_profile` file. I've run `source .bash_profile` and when I run `$ env` from `terminal` I can see the new variable. However, when I run `os.environ` in `python`, it's not there. I'm running `python 3.6.3` in `IDLE` on `OSX 10.13.1`. Is there a way to export new environment variables such that `python` will be able to access them?

Comment: In Unix, an environment variable that is changed in a script or compiled program will only affect that process and possibly child processes. The parent process and any unrelated processes will not be affected.

Comment: I thought exporting variables made them available to other processes? Is there a way to save an environmental variable such that it can be accessed by other processes?

Comment: Exporting variables makes them available to **child processes**. The parent process and any unrelated processes will not be affected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are running Python in IDLE, I suspect you don't start IDLE from the shell for which you've defined your `new_v`. Hence, IDLE does not know about the variable, and neither can Python.

If you execute `python` in your shell and type

```
os.getenv("new_v")
```

you will see your variable. I'm not a Mac user, so I don't know myself how to set env vars in macOS, but this post [Setting environment variables in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x) seems to have an answer :)